# Conditional Expectation Bivariate Normal with OLS

Tags: regression, least-squares, error, conditional-expectation, bivariate

I am working on the effects of omitting variables in a regression for my thesis. I already found a lot about the bias that is created by omitting variables, but not so much about what this does for the estimation error. Therefore I would like to consider the following case:

I know what the true model is (Y is known for a set of test scenarios):

$Y = X_1 \beta_1 + X_2\beta_2$

If I where to include all these regressors I would get a 100% fit.

In the next regression I ommit the second regressor ($X_2$) and we therefore get the misspecified model:

$Y =X_1\beta_1 + \epsilon^*$

It is now virtually impossible to tell something about this error unless we know more about the $X's$ themselves. For simplicity I'll assume that they are bivariately normal distributed and we know the correlation $\rho_{X_1,X_2}$

What can we say about the $\epsilon^*$ in that case? I think the following should be correct, but I am not 100% sure:

$E(\epsilon^*|Y=y)=E(Y-X_1\beta_1 |Y=y)= y - E(X_1\beta_1|Y=y)$

$=y-\beta_1(\mu_{X_1}+\rho_{X_1,Y} \frac{\sigma_{X_1}}{\sigma_Y} (y-\mu_Y))$

Is this correct? Can I find out more about $\epsilon^*$? I could only find literature on the omitted variable bias and not so much on the effect on the error, any literature would also be very welcome.